# Custom Code SSRS 2 fields If Statement

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, if-statement, reporting-services

In my code I am reading each line and if retains the same ID, I am adding a 1 to the 'group number' column I added. I have ran into an issue however, I need to group both ID and PaintNumber and if either is different, it creates a new group number and moves on. This is the custom code I have in SSRS currently.

```
Public CountNumber As Integer = 0

Public Shared Previous as Object

Public Function GroupNumber(ByVal category As Object) As Integer

If Category <> Previous then

CountNumber = CountNumber + 1

Previous=category

Return CountNumber

Else

Return CountNumber

End If
```

End Function

So Im thinking that I could just add my additional field to the code but Im not entirely sure how, but heres my guess:

```
Public CountNumber As Integer = 0

Public Shared Previous as Object

Public Function GroupNumber(ByVal category As Object) As Integer

If Category AND Category2 <> Previous then

CountNumber = CountNumber + 1

Previous=category

Return CountNumber

Else

Return CountNumber

End If

End Function
```

Also, when I call the expression, which in this case Im using "=Code.GroupNumber(ID.Value)", when I add this other field to the custom code, will I have to have both in the expression, like "=Code.GroupNumber(ID.Value,PaintFinish.Value)"

Heres what the data does (First Code) and heres what I'd like the data to do (Second Code)

```
RTYPE   CASEID  QTY BLOCK   FINISH
----------------------------------
CASE    1058769 1   5001    4686
CASE    1023964 1   5001    4686
CASE    1058769 8   5001    4686

CASE    1043742 11  5001    5946
```

second:

```
CASE    1058769 1   5001    4686
CASE    1023964 1   5001    4686
CASE    1058769 1   5001    4686

CASE    1058769 7   5001    5946
CASE    1043742 11  5001    5946
```

It's based off of the CaseID now, and I would like to base it off both CaseID and Finish

Comment: Have you considered some sort of `RunningValue` expression using the `CountDistinct` aggregate? It's very difficult to give an example without some sample data and expected results.

Comment: Yea, Running Value didnt give me the Data I was looking for, at least not the way I was attempting the get it. I can post a code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need two "Previous" variables:  A PreviousCategory and a PreviousCategory2 (I assume one is ID and the other is PaintNumber).

Seems like you only want to compare ID to the previous ID, and PaintNumber to the previous PaintNumber, right?

Comment: Yes, So in my code above, will I have to add another variable, Public Shared Previous2 as Object? Also, would it be an AND? or an ANDALSO? Also as far as the sytanx, should it be Cat<>Prev AND Cat2<>Prev2 or should it be Cat And Cat2 <> Prev and Prev2?

Comment: While this could have worked, I ended up using SSRS to group by Finish first, then implement the top code. It appears to give me the results I was looking, but thanks for your help though!